# L'histoire du vouvoiement

Tags: histoire, vouvoiement

L'un des caractères particuliers du français est le phénomène du vouvoiement. En effet, la différence entre *tu* et *vous* n'existe pas, je crois, dans la plupart des langues du monde, et n'existait pas en latin, langue mère du français. En lisant des romans qui datent du 19ème siècle et du début du 20ème, j'ai aussi pu remarquer que le vouvoiement était beaucoup plus répandu à l'époque qu'aujourd'hui. C'est donc un phénomène grammatical qui est (peut-être sans cesse) en cours de changement.

Je voudrais savoir comment le vouvoiement s'est développé, et pourquoi. Quand est-ce que le pronom pluriel a été inventé, et quand, pourquoi, et comment les Français ont-ils commencé à s'en servir pour marquer le respect ou la distance ? Donnez des références ou de la documentation dans vos réponses, si c'est possible. :)

Comment: Je ne connais pas beaucoup de langues qui n'ont pas de formes de politesse (si c'est bien ça que tu entends par "différence entre tu et vous"). Peux-tu nous en citer ? Il me semble qu'on trouvait cette distinction en anglais également (thou/you).

Comment: Un équivalent du vouvoiement existe aussi dans d'autres langues indo-européennes, notamment l'Allemand, pour lequel l'usage du "Sie" (3ème personne du pluriel) à la place de "du" (2ème personne du singulier) est d'emploi répandu lorsqu'on s'adresse à une personne à qui l'on doit le respect.

Comment: Il y a aussi 'usted' en espagnol. Donc c'est bien quelque chose d'assez commun même si ça perd actuellement (quoique c'est encore largement utilisé dans le monde du travail en France pour démontrer les différences hiérarchiques).

Comment: D'accord avec les autres commentaires : il faudrait remettre la notion 'de la plupart des langues' dans le chapeau d'où elle est sortie :)

Comment: Une autre perspective concernant cette histoire: si on considère la dominance comme l'état primitif humain, et que les langages évoluent, la langue française est dans ce sens plus primitive que la langue anglaise (même pronom pour s'adresser à un adulte qu'à un enfant ou un autre animal). On pourrait y voir dans cette évolution des langages le niveau de civilisation (les langages et les peuples, des larges sociétés, se civiliseraient en abandonnant l'obsession de dominance, entre autres).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apparemment, d'après [cet article](http://clec.uaicf.asso.fr/devorant_cultureaudetail_205.htm) que je cite,

> Le pluriel de majesté apparut sous le règne de Dioclétien, en l'an 285, lorsqu'il devint nécessaire d'instaurer une direction collégiale à la tête de l'Empire romain (le Bas-Empire, ainsi que l'appellent les historiens), celui-ci s'étendant alors de l'Écosse à l'Égypte : ce fut la "tétrarchie", associant deux Augustes [...] à deux Césars [...].
>   Ces empereurs prirent alors l'habitude de s'exprimer à la première personne du pluriel, chacun feignant de parler autant au nom des trois autres qu'au sien propre.

Il est donc vraisemblable qu'en retour, on s'adressait, même qu'à l'un seul d'entre eux avec "vous".
Cela ma semble en tout cas fort plausible.

La suite de l'article est tout aussi marquante:

> Puis l'Âge d'or s'éloignant toujours davantage, et les guerres et troubles succédant aux troubles et aux guerres, les tenants du pouvoir ne surent qu'imposer par la coercition le respect que n'inspiraient plus spontanément leurs façons de mener le monde... Dès lors, le souvenir de son origine ne fut plus que l'apanage de quelques érudits, **et le vouvoiement s'installa dans nos vies comme marque d'une politesse formelle.**

Comment: Ah, réponse équivalent à celle de Jeremy. Je n'avais vu que la page française sur Wikipédia qui, bien que complète, ne donne pas cette notion historique ! :)

Answer (score 15):

There is a fascinating [article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-V_distinction) about this question. It suggests that starting in the fourth century Roman emperors were addressed using the plural "vos", as plurality is a symbol of power.

This usage apparently spread, so that now all Romance languages have a distinction between second person singular forms to express formality/familiarity.

Answer (score 6):

Marcel Cohen signale dans son *Histoire d'une langue : le français* que c'est à l'époque féodale que qu'en France on a commencé à employer  *vous* au lieu de *tu* par
respect pour une personne  mais que l'emploi n'est pas régulier dans les textes.

J'ai trouvé des exemples précis dans :
*Wolff Philippe. Premières recherches sur l'apparition du vouvoiement en latin médiéval. In: Comptes-rendus des séances de l'Académie des Inscriptions et Belles-Lettres, 130e année, N. 2, 1986. pp. 370-383.*
*doi : 10.3406/crai.1986.14393*
http://www.persee.fr/web/revues/home/prescript/article/crai_0065-0536_1986_num_130_2_14393

L'auteur fait une étude de l'utilisation du tutoiement et du vouvoiement dans la correspondance. Il précise qu'il  faudrait aussi examiner les autres types de sources, en particulier les remarques des grammairiens.
En conclusion de l'article :

> Du tutoiement général à l'époque latine classique, nous sommes
>   passés à une dualité tutoiement-vouvoiement, avec de curieux
>   passages d'une forme à l'autre dans certaines lettres. Deux étapes
>   paraissent pouvoir être signalées : l'une, entre le IIe et le IVe siècle,
>   c'est l'apparition du vouvoiement dans certaines formules de politesse ; mais il reste à lier à ces formules un sentiment profond de révérence, qui amène à étendre l'usage du vouvoiement à l'ensemble du discours. Il semble bien que cette mutation se soit accomplie à l'époque carolingienne. Nous ne saurions d'autre part trop insister
>   sur la signification, à la fois psychologique et sociale, de cette
>   mutation.

Answer (score 1):

Simplement une comparaison des vouvoiements et de leurs significations à l'époque contemporaine.

En France, le vouvoiement est la manière normale de s'adresser à une personne que vous ne connaissez pas et sous-entend, sinon un certain respect, du moins une certaine réserve dans la familiarité. Vous pourrez remarquer, si vous avez assisté en France, à des confrontations verbales, par exemple entre automobilistes, qu'un seuil significatif d'agressivité est franchi lorsqu'un (au moins) des protagonistes se met à tutoyer son interlocuteur : il semble en fait assez difficile d'insulter quelqu'un en le vouvoyant, mais cela peut se pratiquer, au risque de l'incompréhension d'une de parties.
Toujours en France, le tutoiement est courant entre gens jeunes et avec les personnes familières et requiert malgré tout une certaine proximité, réelle ou supposée.

En Italie, il m'a toujours semblé que le tutoiement était très rapide, que l'on s'adressait à vous d'abord par exemple comme "lei", puis assez vite, on passait au tutoiement. Ce n'est à mon avis pas une marque de familiarité, mais une sorte de désir social d'éviter cette période d'attente avant la familiarité et de sauter l'étape des préliminaires. C'est un grand classique des films français d'avant les années soixante-dix d'entendre un couple d'abord se vouvoyer et, séduction consommée, de se tutoyer, signifiant au spectateur, même s'il est endormi, que les héros sont passés à l'acte et ont atteint le degré ultime de la familiarité. Un autre grand classique aujourd'hui presque disparu est le vouvoiement entre époux, presque un oxymoron. Il était relativement fréquent dans les années cinquante dans les milieux qui se considéraient eux-mêmes comme aisés ou désireux d'assurer l'apparence d'une certaine tenue ; ce vouvoiement-là a maintenant presque complètement disparu, probablement victime des réflexions graveleuses qu'il suscitait.

Le vouvoiement est très présent en Russie, un pays où l'on ne tutoie que les très proches. Il y a dans la langue russe plusieurs poids pour le vouvoiement et c'est une  marque de respect que de s'adresser à quelqu'un en utilisant son patronyme "Cher Dmitri Ivanovitch", qui recèle une familiarité respectueuse, et je ne peux penser en français à aucune expression équivalente, qui convoque l'ascendance de votre interlocuteur avec une certaine déférence. Bien entendu, il est impossible de s'adresser à un inconnu de la sorte, et j'ai l'impression que ce dosage subtil est ignoré par le français aussi bien que par l'anglais et que les russes disposent dans leur langue d'un éventail plus riche.

Answer (score 0):

J'aimerais avancer une hypothèse un peu semblable sur le fond aux deux empereurs romains, je n'ai aucune preuve ni fait de recherches sur le sujet mais c'est par déduction que je l'avance.
En règle générale, (sauf peut-être à l'égard d'un jeune prince) on ne vouvoie que des adultes. Mon hypothèse est que lorsque l'on dit "vous" on s'adresse à la personne comme représentante d'un couple supposé, qui peut être vu comme une entité plurielle composée de deux moitiés (la femme et le mari). Le un dual est ce que l'on peut appeler le monisme dialectique, présent dans le taoïsme ou représenté dans les mythologies (Janus par exemple), dans la Tradition en somme. Comprendre que le couple est une personne faite de deux corps qui naît lors de leur union (=faire un).
L'idée est donc que le vouvoiement s'adresserait spécifiquement, et originellement, à une personne qui est en âge de se marier, une personne complète d'une certaine manière, et suis les mêmes raisons de politesse évoquées concernant les empereurs romains (qui est un "vous" plus hiérarchique).
Tutoyer une dame mariée reviendrait en quelque sorte à l'appeler Mademoiselle, le vouvoiement est donc plus formel et poli lorsque l'on s'adresse à un(e) inconnu(e). D'un autre côté, bien connaître une personne permet de mieux pouvoir la dissocier de son couple (concernant ses choix, ses actions etc.) et ainsi un "tu" est surement plus adéquate car plus certain (typiquement dans le cadre familial, le tutoiement d'un adulte fait donc partie du registre familier).