# Si vous êtes intéressé(s)

Tags: accord, histoire, vouvoiement

Dans cette 
[question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27276/tu-or-vous-in-an-advert), il a été proposé d'utiliser "vous" en se cachant derrière l'ambiguïté du "vous" (est-ce le tutoiement ou le vouvoiement au pluriel ?) pour contourner le problème.

J'en suis venu à me poser une question : si l'on voulait "vouvoyer au singulier", devrait-on écrire "si vous êtes intéressé" ou "si vous êtes intéressés" ? Il me paraîtrait très étrange d'écrire "Vous êtes malades." ou "Vous êtes allemands." pour une seule personne, donc j'imagine que la convention moderne est d'accorder sémantiquement et non syntaxiquement, d'autant que c'est plus précis : on peut ainsi faire la différence entre les vouvoiements singulier et pluriel.

Cependant, qu'en est-t-il historiquement ? Accordait-on au pluriel quand on employait le pluriel de majesté, à l'origine ?

Comment: Je n'en sais rien pour l'histoire (à rechercher je suppose) mais du point de vue synchronique c'est nettement comme tu le dis : On fait la distinction entre *vous* singulier et *vous* pluriel pour l'accord. Pour vérifier avec l'oreille, dirais-tu "Vous êtes très originaux" où "original" à une seule personne ?

Comment: Oui je suis d'accord. C'est pour cette raison aussi que la question porte sur l'histoire, car j'imagine qu'à l'origine il fallait accorder mais ce n'est qu'une supposition.

Comment: Quelques informations et liens ici: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3/lhistoire-du-vouvoiement... mais qui ne répondent pas à la question, sauf erreur de ma part

Comment: Après quelques recherches, il semble que ce "vous" découle d'un "nous" de majesté. Ce "nous" impliquait-il un "s" ? C'est peut-être une piste pour trouver un élément de réponse.

Comment: J'ai cherché dans l'édit de Nantes (ici : http://huguenotsweb.free.fr/histoire/edit_nantes.htm ) et on y trouve "nous étant [...] succédé," dans le second paragraphe donc je suppose que succédé n'est pas accordé (même si je ne comprends pas ce que cette phrase signifie). Mais je ne sais pas dans quelle mesure l'orthographe a été modernisée...

Answer (score 3):

Le vouvoiement ne fait pas de "vous" un pluriel (sauf pour l'accord du verbe). On dira donc:

> Vous êtes intéressant(e).
>   Vous êtes un bon ami.

Sans mettre la marque du pluriel pour le COD.

Il est difficile de donner une vérité historique car l'orthographe officielle n'a pas toujours existé: [l'Académie Française date seulement du XVIIe siècle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographe_fran%C3%A7aise#Histoire) et on utilisait le vouvoiement depuis bien avant.

Pour la majesté, on a surtout utilisé la troisième personne du singulier:

> Votre Altesse est-elle intéressée ?

plutôt que la seconde du pluriel.

Comment: Dans "votre Altesse est-elle intéressée", on utilise la deuxième du pluriel pour le pronom possessif. Pour ce qui est des sources historiques, je ne demande rien d'officiel. Je voudrais seulement savoir si l'usage a été attesté à un moment ou un autre. Mon hypothèse est que quand le vouvoiement a été "inventé", on poussait jusqu'au bout la fiction de s'adresser à plusieurs personnes. Mais je peux me tromper, et c'est pourquoi je pose cette question. Merci quand même pour ces éléments de réponse.

Comment: "Son altesse" existe aussi. D'ailleurs en espagnol par exemple (qui a des racines très proches) le vouvoiement est remplacé par l'usage de la troisième personne (*usted(es)*).

Comment: J'ai fait une recherche rapide sur google n-gram. "vous estes belles" n'est pas trouvé alors que "vous estes belle" a des occurences entre 1650 et 1700. ("êtes" avec un accent circonflexe, lui, n'existe pas encore à cette époque). Je pense donc que votre hypothèse est fausse sinon on n'aurait pas "vous estes belle".

Comment: Merci pour ces informations. Cela dit, il y a une petite erreur dans votre réponse : le verbe ne s'accorde pas entièrement, car dans le cas des temps composés ("vous êtes arrivé, vous êtes tombé") et du passif ("vous êtes intéressé" justement) on n'accorde pas non plus le participe passé.